# C++ function that takes a 2 Dimensional array and returns the position of the first row with an odd sum or returns -1 if no odd sums

Tags: c++

I am very new to coding in c++, and in general. I need to create a function that takes a 2D array and returns the position of the first row with an odd sum. If there are now rows with odd sums, the function should return -1.

This is what my code currently looks like, but I can't get it to return -1, unless I include the commented out portion. But then it stops at that line and won't continue because it closes the program.

I am trying to figure out where to put the else statement in question so that my function works.

```
int rowOddSum(int arr[6][4])
{
    int r, c, sum = 0;
    // finding the row sum
    for (r = 0; r < 6; r++) {
        for (c = 0; c < 4; c++){ 
            sum = sum + arr[r][c];
        }

        if (sum % 2 != 0) {
            cout
                << "Sum of the row "
                << r << " is odd: " << sum
                << endl;
            return r;
        }

// the else statement in question
        /*                   
        else {
            return -1;
        }
        */

        sum = 0;   // Resets the sum
    }
}

int main() {
    int arr[6][4] = {
        {2,0,2,2},
        {2,2,0,4},
        {2,2,0,4},
        {2,2,0,0},
        {2,7,0,2},
        {2,2,4,4} 
    };
     rowOddSum(arr);
}
```

Comment: `rowOddSum()` does not return any value at the end. This is undefined behavior.

Comment: There is no need for the `else`.  If the entire set of loops doesn't find an odd row, then just return `-1` at the end.

Comment: What @PaulMcKenzie said. This is a pretty common pattern: You search for something, and if you find it, you exit early with whatever you found as soon as you find it. If you don't find anything at all, you return a (known) default value, but you need to truly check everything before you do.

Comment: You don't use the return value from `rowOddSum()` in the `main()` function.  If you are not going to use the return value, then declare the function's return type as `void`.

Comment: Your code is ok. Just move return -1 out of for loop and as last statement in your function ```rowOddSum()``` . If you want to see -1, just change 7 at arr[4][1] to even value. And do ```cout << rowOddSum()```; in ```main()```

Comment: Some tips on style. Get in the habit of creating local variables where they’re first needed, which usually isn’t at the top of the function. So `for (int r = 0; r < 6; r++)` and similarly for the inner loop. And move `int sum = 0;` so it’s the first statement inside the outer `for` loop. Also, use `'\n'` to end a line unless you need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does.

Comment: Put `return -1` after the outer for loop block's `}`.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for everyone who would like to write the above code in a more current C++ style.

```
#include <array>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

// Using special values like -1 to indicate something is not found
// requires the caller to know about the special value and check for it
// which requires extra documentation and is error prone
// std::optional (or a struct with a bool of your own) may be used to 
// indicate you might not find a correct answer.
// 
// Use std::array instead of C style arrays
// pass by const reference to avoid copying and to ensure the function 
// does not modify the values in your array

std::optional<int> rowOddSum(const std::array<std::array<int,4>,6>& values)
{
    int row_index{0};

    // In C++ prefer range based for loops over traditional for loops
    // to avoid going out of bounds, and code stays correct
    // when you change the size of the array.
    for(const auto& row : values)
    {
       // When summing something use std::accumulate shows WHAT you are doing instead of HOW
       auto sum = std::accumulate(row.begin(), row.end(), 0);

       // Use bitwise operations instead of modulo for better performance
       if (sum&1) return std::optional{row_index};

       ++row_index;       
    }
       
    // if you ran through all the rows and didn't find an odd sum there isn't one
    // return an optional without value
    return std::optional<int>{};
}

int main() 
{
   // the `const` promise you made was not guaranteed by your initial code with "C" style arrays
   // by passing by const reference to values the compiler will enforce the promise you made
   const std::array<std::array<int,4>,6> values{{
        {2,0,2,2},
        {2,2,0,4},
        {2,2,0,4},
        {2,2,0,0},
        {2,7,0,2},
        {2,2,4,4} 
       }};
    
   auto result = rowOddSum(values);

   // Now we can use the result of the function to print the result
   if ( result.has_value() )
   {
       std::cout << "Row " << result.value() << " has an odd sum\n";
   }
   else
   {
       std::cout << "No row has an odd sum\n";
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Pepijn Kramer, I'd prefer to write the code in what I'd consider at least reasonably modern style, but I have a slightly different take on how to do that.

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

// Define the type of the array in one place:
using Array = std::array<std::array<int, 4>, 6>;

auto rowOddSum(Array const& values) {

    return std::find_if(values.begin(), values.end(), 
        [](auto const &row) { return std::accumulate(row.begin(), row.end(), 0) & 1 == 1; });
}

int main() {
    const Array values = {{
        {2,0,2,2},
        {2,2,0,4},
        {2,2,0,4},
        {2,2,0,0},
        {2,7,0,2},
        {2,2,4,4} 
    }};
    
    auto result = rowOddSum(values);

    if (result == values.end()) {
        std::cout << "None of the rows has an odd sum\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Row " << result - values.begin() << " has an odd sum\n";
    }
}
```

If we didn't want to pre-define the type, we could turn `rowOddSum` into a function template instead, but this adds a fair amount of template "stuff" that departs enough further from the original that its similarity to the original can become hard to recognize.

Answer (score 0):

Great answers around.
This is based on them, @JerryCoffin 's and @PepijnKramer 's.

Whatever you do, use a proper two- (or multi-) dimensional array library that you will need anyway once you move to dynamic (runtime) sizes.

```
#include <multi/array.hpp>  // from https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi (disclaimer: I wrote this lib)

#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <optional>

namespace multi = boost::multi;

int main() {
    auto const values = multi::array<int, 2>{
        {2, 0, 2, 2}, 
        {2, 2, 0, 4}, 
        {2, 2, 0, 4},
        {2, 2, 0, 0}, 
        {2, 7, 0, 2}, 
        {2, 2, 4, 4},
    };

    constexpr auto rowOddSum = [](auto const& values) {
        return std::find_if(
            values.begin(), values.end(),
            [](auto const& row) {return std::accumulate(row.begin(), row.end(), 0) & 1 == 1;}
        );
    };

    auto const result = rowOddSum(values);

    if (result != values.end()) {
        std::cout << "Row with index " << result - values.begin() << " has an odd sum\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "No row has an odd sum\n";
    }
}
```

using iterators: https://godbolt.org/z/1Ece8h41q

using indices: https://godbolt.org/z/qe3dqvaK5

using ranges: https://godbolt.org/z/dETjKTr5P

Comment: Thanks for the input! Got it running with your suggestions